# What's happening assigning a list expression inside parenthesis to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parentheses

Playing with the Babel REPL to check how to use variable as object literals property name I found that

```
var y = { [X] : 'x', [Y] : 'y' };

// is translated to:

// ... _defineProperty definition ...
var _y;
var y = (_y = {}, _defineProperty(_y, X, 'x'), _defineProperty(_y, Y, 'y'), _y);
```

Now, I understand what is happening in _defineProperty, but someone could explain me what's happening inside the parentheses?

Are the statement inside `()` executed in order and only the last statement result is returned?

Comment: The answer is "yes" ;)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates all the expression and returns the result of the last one, e.g.

```
a(), b(), c(); // Calls `a`, `b` and `c`, and returns the value returned by `c`
```

In you case, the wrapping parentheses are also needed because of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).